# Prevent subprocess from inheriting file descriptors

Tags: fork

Is there a safe and easy way of executing a subprocess, while not allowing it to have access to the parents file descriptors? Particularly in my case this happens:

1. The parent process listens to socket 127.0.0.1:8000.
2. The parent process uses exec to run a sub process. This sub process forks and starts a daemon.
3. The parent process closes.

The daemon now keeps the file descriptor open (keeps listening to port 8000).

Perhaps there is some command that can close all file descriptors before executing the sub process?

This problem occurs for example if you call the 'service someservice start'' commands from a web server script.

Perhaps there is some command that could run the service script in a "clean" context, something like:

```
run-detached service someservice start
```

Which would cause all file descriptors to be closed, environment variables to be unset and so on - so that the context the service runs within is as basic as possible.

Comment: See [`FD_CLOEXEC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)

Comment: [You are not the first person to do this](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/bsd-service-command.html#Inheritance), but the right approach is to not start dæmons that way in the first place and use real service management, not to look for ways to bodge the child processes.

Comment: It's up to the program which `fork()`s to close unneeded file descriptors (or mark them as close-on-exec) before `exec()`ing a new program.  It's not something you can impose from outside as a sysadmin.  (For advice on the programming aspects, you might want to head over to [so]).

Comment: @JdeBP You should tell that to the people that created the ifup command. It in some cases spawns a dhclient process and a wpa_supplicant process. The right approach is in no way to modify the source code of other peoples software - and I am merely looking for a proper way to run such processes in a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close file descriptors from outside the process (for obvious good reasons).

One thing you could do is to create a small shim for the program that is to be run in the subprocess, and convince the parent to `exec()` that instead (e.g. by putting it in place of the original).  This small program can then close file descriptors and then exec the original program.

Comment: I am hoping there is a standard Linux command that is able to fork, then the fork closes FDs except std*, and run a process and then the parent waits for the fork to finish before returning to the main program. It should be a common scenario.